# Make array work according to condition

Tags: android

i want only specific images to be loaded according to the condition.
but now wat is happening everytime same images gets loaded.
ex: if the variable list is fetching value 1 then only R.drawable.shiva and R.drawable.iskon has to be loaded
my java file is as follows

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {




    Context context;


    int[] GalImages = new int[]{
            R.drawable.chokkanatha1,
            R.drawable.chokkanatha2,
            R.drawable.chokkanatha3,
            R.drawable.chokkanatha4,
            R.drawable.chokkanatha5,
            R.drawable.chokkanatha6};



   public ImageAdapter(Context context,String list1){


        this.context=context;
       String list =list1;


       if(list.equals("0"))

       {
          int[] GalImages = new int[]{
                   R.drawable.chokkanatha1,
                   R.drawable.chokkanatha2,
                   R.drawable.chokkanatha3,
                   R.drawable.chokkanatha4,
                   R.drawable.chokkanatha5,
                   R.drawable.chokkanatha6
           };
       }

       if(list.equals("1"))

       {

           int[] GalImages = new int[]{
                   R.drawable.shiva,
                   R.drawable.iskon

           };

           Log.d("message", list.toString());

       }

    }



//    private int position;
//    ImageAdapter(Context context, int position) {
//        this.context = context;
//        this.position = position;
//
//        Log.d("message", "test");
//    }




    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.d("message", "test");
        return GalImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {




        // Log.d("message", "position");



        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

        //imageView.getItem(myViewPager.getCurrentItem());

        // int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
        // imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setImageResource(GalImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Logical error, you are creating new instances of the array, not updating the existing one. Here:

```
public ImageAdapter(Context context,String list1){


        this.context=context;
       String list =list1;


       if(list.equals("0"))

       {
          //Do not specify the int[] type before the variable name
          GalImages = new int[]{
                   R.drawable.chokkanatha1,
                   R.drawable.chokkanatha2,
                   R.drawable.chokkanatha3,
                   R.drawable.chokkanatha4,
                   R.drawable.chokkanatha5,
                   R.drawable.chokkanatha6
           };
       }

       if(list.equals("1"))

       {
           //Same here
           GalImages = new int[]{
                   R.drawable.shiva,
                   R.drawable.iskon

           };

           Log.d("message", list.toString());

       }

    }
```

Also, it is standard in Java to name fields and variables with lowercase letter at the beginning and then normal camelcase, so `galImages`

Comment: Just do not specify the type before the variable name. See the code I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring the variable GalImages inside each of the if blocks, so it's scope is local and the instance variable remains untouched.

You should do:

```
   if(list.equals("0"))
   {
      GalImages = new int[]{
               R.drawable.chokkanatha1,
               R.drawable.chokkanatha2,
               R.drawable.chokkanatha3,
               R.drawable.chokkanatha4,
               R.drawable.chokkanatha5,
               R.drawable.chokkanatha6
       };
   }

   if(list.equals("1"))
   {
       GalImages = new int[]{
               R.drawable.shiva,
               R.drawable.iskon

       };
       Log.d("message", list.toString());
   }
```